# How to make magento 1.9 to use postfix to send email to client?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email, magento-cron, smtp

I have Magento store deployed on an ec2 instance which was moved from shared hosting to the standalone server on AWS.
On the server I have configured Postfix as the MTA agent to allow Magento to send emails about orders and transaction details.
On the shared server, the emails would be sent to the customer correctly.

But on EC2 instance Magento is unable to send the emails.
How can I make Magento send client Emails?

Postfix is configured correctly and I am able to send Test emails from the command line using postfix from port 25.